# Ein neutraler Ausdruck für "soziale Medien"?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche einen Begriff, mit dem man in der deutschen Sprache den Ausdruck "soziale Medien" besser - das heißt neutraler und sachlich angemessener - ersetzen kann.

Der Begriff "soziale Medien" ist eine direkte Übersetzung aus dem Amerikanischen (social media). Während ich mit dem englischen Begriff gut zurecht komme, stoße ich mich am deutschen "soziale Medien" jedesmal, vor allem wenn ich in einem sachlichen (wissenschaftlichen) Text präzise, klischeefreie und inhaltlich korrekte Sprache verwenden will. "Sozial" im Deutschen hat für mich zu stark einen Bedeutungsanteil von "Sorge für die anderen". Das "sozial" in "social media" meint aber nicht "Sorge für die anderen" sondern "jedermann" bzw. "in Kontakt treten".

Ich vermute, es ist relativ leicht, ironische, kritische und despektierliche Begriffe zu finden. Solche zu sammeln, wird auch amüsant sein. So ist zum Beispiel der Alternativbegriff

> asoziale Medien

bei Kritikern derselben  beliebt und verbreitet. Das ist aber natürlich sowohl ironisch als auch provokativ gemeint.

Mir geht es hier um einen nicht wertenden Ausdruck - weder negativ noch positiv.<sup>1</sup>

- Ich bin bisher gekommen auf:

> kommerzielle Meinungsaustauschplattform

- Verbreitet ist die Lösung, "soziale Medien" in Gänsefüßchen zu setzen. Damit zeigt der Autor, dass er den Begriff kritisch betrachtet. Ich suche aber einen echten verbalen Ausdruck, keine typographische Krücke.
- Eine weitere Methode, die denkbar ist: Man spricht von "*das was gemeinhin als soziale Medien bezeichnet wird*". Aber da ist man natürlich schon nahe an Dr. Murkes "*jenes höhere Wesen, das wir verehren*" (Heinrich Böll: "Doktor Murkes gesammeltes Schweigen", 1955)

Welche Möglichkeiten gibt es noch?

---

<sup>1</sup> Unter "Neutralität" verstehe ich hier aber auch, dass der Begriff nicht etwa vorgaukelt, es handle sich um eine rein zwischen freien Individuen laufende Kommunikation wie auf einem öffentlichen Platz, denn die "Plätze", auf denen diese Kommunikation in der Praxis stattfindet, sind ja allesamt hochkommerzieller Natur, das heißt, eingerichtet von Dritten mit Gewinnerzielungsabsicht (die aber geflissentlich verborgen wird). Es ist eigentlich dieser Umstand, der mich beim Begriff "soziale Medien" immer zusammenzucken lässt.

Comment: Eine kürzere Form der dritten Variante wäre *"die **sogenannten** sozialen Medien"* - würde das der geforderten Neutralität entsprechen?

Comment: @Arsak  Es ist in der Tat eine recht häufig gebrauchte Wendung (schon weil andere bisher nicht verbreitet sind). Ich bin nur nicht recht glücklich damit, weil die Distanzierung, die man damit ausdrückt, sehr stark ist; für mich jedenfalls geht das schon über Neutralität hinaus in Richtung expliziter Kritik. Wenn das Thema des Textes nicht speziell die Kritik am Phänomen "soziale Medien" ist, hätte ich gerne einen weniger offensiven Begriff.

Comment: Ist es denn überhaupt sinnvoll Facebook, Twitter, Instragram usw. in den gleichen Topf zu schmeißen? Sie werden von den Nutzern für unterschiedliche Zwecke benutzt und haben auch unterschiedliche Interaktionsweisen. Ich stieß auf diese Frage, als ich darüber nachgedacht habe was du mit "soziale Medien" überhaupt meinst.

Comment: Fn1 ist recht lustig: er besagt, dass ein neutraler Ausdruck für eine durch und durch doppelplusungute Erscheinung gesucht wird; also ein Euphemismus? Scheint mir, gesucht wird lediglich ein Begriff, der weniger 'grob' daherkommt, da "asozial" als Volltreffer auch für unsere amerikanische FlakExchange overlords wohl als 'rude' zu flaggen *gildet* (um das stilistisch mal auf dem Niveau der SE-flakflagger zu belassen). Auch "Distanzierung" ist eine Positionierung?

Comment: Auch im Englischen kommt es mitunter zur Verballhornung des Begriffs als "antisocial media".

Comment: @problemofficer: Die Gemeinsamkeit wird erst auf einer höheren Abstraktionsstufe sichtbar. Meiner Meinung nach besteht diese darin, dass "soziale Medien" Plattformen sind, deren zentraler Verwendungszweck für die Nutzer darin besteht, Nachrichten für andere Nutzer - insbesondere auch für Gruppen davon - zu hinterlassen.

Comment: Zur Fußnote: Gilt es hier nicht, die Verwendung aus Nutzersicht vom konkreten Aufbau der zugrundeliegenden Organisation zu unterscheiden? Wäre beispielsweise eine Plattform, die aus Nutzersicht ähnlich wie (o.B.d.A.) Facebook funktioniert, mit einer Art persönlicher Pinnwand für Nachrichten an alle oder bestimmte andere Nutzer, welche aber beispielsweise als quelloffene Software von einer gemeinnützigen Organisation betrieben wird, für dich in einer gänzlich anderen Kategorie als die bisherigen "sozialen Medien"? Letztendlich werden Produkte ja häufig nach dem Verwendungszweck benannt, ...

Comment: ... nicht nach dem im konkreten Fall vielleicht dahinterstehenden Geschäftsmodell. Schließlich werden Unterhaltungsfernsehen und Vergnügungsparks trotz des Namens auch nicht aus reiner Menschenfreundlichkeit zur allgemeinen Erheiterung betrieben.

Comment: Ich denke es wird für Verwirrung sorgen, einen wohlverstandenen und genutzten Begriff durch einen anderen zu ersetzen. Zu Freunde treffen sagt man ebenso scherzhaft "soziale Kontakte pflegen". Sprache wandelt sich nunmal und gerade das Englische findet viel Einzug, ob nun als Übersetzung oder direkt als Wort. Kann man gut finden, kann man schlecht finden, aber Widerstand ist zwecklos.

Comment: Bei "gemeinhin als soziale Medien bezeichnet" geht dir Neutralität verloren, weil du da durchscheinen lässt, dass du mit dem Begriff nicht einverstanden bist.

Comment: Nicht alle sozialen Medien sind kommerziell, schon gar nicht hochkommerziell. Auch besagt "sozial" nicht, dass man von der Sorge um andere angetrieben ist. Mir scheint Du versuchst die Quadratur des Kreises - Du willst Deine Wertung unmissverständlich zum Ausdruck bringen aber zugleich neutral wirken.

Comment: @userunknown  Wie verstehst du - auf Deutsch - das Wort "sozial"? -  Zur Kreisquadratur: Ja, da gebe ich Dir recht, meine Frage entsand aus verschiedenen, teils widersprüchlichen Motiven. Aber wenn ich schon ein tendenziöses Wort verwenden muss, möchte ich die Tendenz lieber selber bestimmen.

Comment: Zwischenmenschliche Interaktionen betreffend.

Comment: "kommerzielle Meinungsaustauschplattform" hat auch eine sekundäre Bedeutung: da kann man seine Meinung auf andere, mehr "Kommerzielle" tauschen ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Du könntest es auch wie auf der Wikipedia machen und einfach *[social media](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Media)* als uneingedeutschtes Fremdwort verwenden.

Ich würde allerdings davon abraten, einen neuen Begriff zu prägen. Der Ausdruck *soziale Medien* hat sich trotz allfälliger Problematik nun einmal etabliert. Anführungszeichen oder einschränkende Zusätze wie «sogenannte» drücken kaum weniger ironisierende Distanz aus als der Kalauer von den «antisozialen» Medien. In einer Sprachglosse mag so etwas angebracht sein, aber nicht in einem wissenschaftlichen Text. Da sind Begriffe zwar kritisch zu beleuchten und zu systematisieren, aber von einem etablierten Sprachgebrauch würde ich nur dann abweichen, wenn es die Neuartigkeit des Gegenstands unbedingt erfordert.

Übrigens bin ich mir durchaus nicht sicher, ob die Konnotationen des deutschen Worts *sozial* auch wirklich sich derart unterscheiden von denjenigen des englischen Worts *social.* Meiner Meinung nach tun sie es nicht, aber ich bin da kein Spezialist.

Comment: Den zweiten Punkt (ob "sozial" im Deutschen von den meisten Sprachnutzern so verstanden wird, wie ich es behauptet habe, nämlich als "in Sorge um den anderen") finde ich interessant, und ich bin gespannt, hier Neues zu lernen. - Den ersten Punkt (dass man etablierte  Begriffe verwenden soll, weil sie halt etabliert sind) finde ich für meine Frage irreführend. Wenn ich mich nicht bewusst entschieden hätte, gegen den Strom der leichtfertig akzeptierten Begrifflichkeiten zu schwimmen, hätte ich die ganze Frage ja gar nicht gestellt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Mich dünkt viel eher die Rede von «leichtfertig akzeptierten Begrifflichkeiten» irreführend, wenn es um wissenschaftliche Wortwahl geht. Die Rede von Leichtfertigkeit, Akzeptierung oder Gegen-den-Strom-schwimmen-Wollen gehören zur Gattung der Sprachglossen. In einem wissenschaftlichen Text würde ich hingegen erwarten, dass der existierende Sprachgebrauch zwar untersucht und hinterfragt, dann aber – derart geläutert – übernommen wird.

Comment: Hinterfragen schließt nach meinem Verständnis das Übernehmen aus. Oder aber, wenn ich nach dem Hinterfragen (und ggf. Fürproblematischbefinden) dann doch übernehme, dann war mein Hinterfragen verlorene Mühe.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Es ist ganz einfach der hermeneutische Zirkel. Nach einer Umdrehung ist man zwar wieder am gleichen Ort, aber reicher an Erkenntnis. Und Hinterfragen bedeutet ja nicht ablehnen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich würde es nicht Hinterfragen nennen, wenn das gewünschte Ergebnis vorab feststeht, sondern Bestreiten. "Sozial" ist nun mal doppeldeutig im Deutschen; es bedeutet sowohl das neutrale "in Bezug auf andere Menschen" als auch "empathiegeleitet". Dass jmd. glauben könnte, Twitter- oder Facebooknutzung sei empathiegeleitet ist die schräge Prämisse, die man macht, um den Witz von den asozialen oder antisozialen Medien anzubringen. Solche Satire für bare Münze zu nehmen, ist, meine ich, Dein Fehler.

Comment: @userunknown  Ich gebe Dir in allem Recht. Einzig der Unterstellung, ich unterschlüge die Bedeutungsvarianten von "sozial" im Deutschen möchte ich widersprechen. Ich glaube, mein Problem mit "soziale Medien" kommt nicht von der Vieldeutigkeit des Begriffs "sozial" im Deutschen, sondern von der gedankenlosen und schiefen Übernahme des Begriffs aus dem Amerikanischen. Ich glaube, im Amerikanischen ist bei "social" das Bedeutungslement "viele Leute, die miteinander kommunizieren" vorherrschend. Ich meine, im Deutschen ist das anders.

Comment: ... Indiz: Man sagt ja im Amerikanischen auch "social event" (und meint damit eine Party), man würde aber im Deutschen dafür nie "soziales Event" oder "soziales Ereignis" oder "soziale Veranstaltung" sagen, es sei denn man drückte sich bewusst ironisch oder gestelzt aus. Aber schon bei "soziale Veranstaltung" sind wir eher bei einem von der Feuerwehr ausgerichteten Weihnachtsfestessen für Obdachlose.

Comment: Ja, da würde man vielleicht von einer Gemeinschaftsveranstaltung sprechen. Gemeinschaftsmedien sagt aber m.W. niemand, oder behaupten wir, zur Sicherheit und Präzision lieber "fast niemand", "kaum wer" oder "wenige". Allerdings gab es früher das Fach "Sozialkunde" - k.A. ob das inzw. umbenannt wurde, da steht sozial auch für die Gemeinschaft betreffend, nicht für Hilfsbereitschaft. Daher sollte jeder Interessierte wissen, was das Wort bedeutet.

Answer (score 1):

Ich fürchte, alle Alternativformulierungen werden zunächst mal länger. Dass 'sozial' in der deutschen Sprache nach 'Sozialfall', 'sozialer Benachteiligung', 'sozialer Randgruppe', 'Sozialdienst' und Ähnlichem riecht, ist nur die eine Seite der Medaille und außerdem eine abgeleitete 'Bedeutung' bzw. eine eher verkürzte Ausdrucksweise für die eigentlich gemeinten 'problematischen Bereiche im sozialen Gesamtgefüge'. Solche unschönen und ungenauen Verkürzungen kenne ich von 'biologischem Gemüse' oder 'unethischem Verhalten'. 'Sozial' hat allerdings weitere Bedeutungsanteile; das hier genannte 'Sorge für die anderen' wäre etwa bei [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sozial) die Bedeutung 4

Auch das Wort 'Medium' hat in seiner Anwendung auf eine Internetplattform etwas Auslegungsfähiges. Er steht für mich in Zusammenhang mit 'Massenmedium' - auch die 'sozialen Medien' sind ein Massenphänomen, und sie zielen wie die Massenmedien auf die Öffentlichkeit, funktionieren aber per Zugangsbeschränkungen eher wie Clubs.

Ich finde, 'Kommunikationsplattform' trifft es sehr gut, nur ist der Begriff unhandlich. 'Internetbasierte Bühne für soziale Interaktion' ist noch weitaus unhandlicher und auch kein ernst gemeinter Formulierungsvorschlag, in dem obendrein der Aspekt der kommerziellen Verwertung noch fehlt. 'Virtuelle Arena für Meinungsabsonderungen ohne soziale Verantwortung' wäre deutlich polemisch und zielt nur auf die negativen Aspekte. 'Werbefinanzierter digitaler Tummelplatz für soziales Mit- und Gegeneinander': auch wieder zu lang und zu umständlich...

Mit einem Wort: Keine Idee.

Comment: Ich  muss dir leider widersprechen. Von "keine Idee" kann keine Rede sein. Ich habe drei bis vier gar nicht schlechte Vorschläge erspäht. *Internetbasierte Bühne für Meinungsabsonderungen ohne soziale Verantwortung* (ein Mix aus den verschiedenen Vorschlägen) scheint mir allgemein recht treffend... :-)

Comment: Das lässt sich gut in einen Kommentar einbauen, aber nicht in einen wissenschaftlichen Text.

Answer (score 0):

Wer immer das englische Wort "social" mit dem deutschen "sozial" zum ersten Mal im Zusammenhang mit "social media" übersetzt hat, hätte vorher in den Duden schauen sollen. Da heißt es unter "sozial":

1. die Gesellschaft betreffend,
2. gesellschaftlich,
3. gemeinnützig,
4. wohltätig.

Im englisch-deutschen Wörterbuch hingegen steht unter "social":

1. gesellig,
2. gesellschaftlich,
3. sozial.

Während also der deutsche Begriff zunächst bierernst politisch daherkommt, bevor er ins Gemeinnützige und Wohltätige abbiegt, ist "social" im Englischen zuallererst privat-gesellig, dann erst öffentlich-gesellschaftlich, bevor er ins Soziale abgleitet, bis hin zu sozialistisch.
Gibt es eine adäquate Übersetzung des Begriffs "social", die den privat-geselligen Aspekt abbildet? Die "geselligen" Medien etwa? Nein, klingt irgendwie nach Stammtisch, obwohl - ganz widersinnig wäre das nicht.
Aber es gibt noch ein anderes Wort: "soziabel"! Der Duden beschreibt es als

1. umgänglich,
2. gesellig.

Pech nur, dass diesen Ausdruck kaum einer kennt und benutzt, denn er stammt aus der Zoologie und gilt für das Verhalten von Herdentieren. Nicht ganz abwegig in diesem Fall, wenn man bedenkt, wie sich Chatgruppen im Netz verhalten.

Aber gewöhnen wir uns vielleicht daran:

"Soziabel" ist etymologisch und phonetisch verwandt mit "social" und "sozial", ist nur um eine Silbe länger, und endlich hätten wir eine neue Bedeutung für ein viel zu selten benutztes Wort! Vielleicht mal ein positives Beispiel, wie ein Begriff aus dem Tierreich auf den Menschen überspringen kann, ohne eine Pandemie auszulösen.

Answer (score -1):

Zunächst einmal würde ich auch dringend davon abraten einen nicht etablierten Begriff zu verwenden. Dafür sind social media / soziale Medien viel zu verbreitet und allgemein akzeptiert. Ob man diesen nun mag oder nicht.

Aber wenn man denn unbedingt will, es gibt in Deutschland für alles einen Verein, so auch den (relativ bekannten) Verein Deutsche Sprache, der auf seiner Internetseite einen [Anglizismenindex](https://vds-ev.de/denglisch-und-anglizismen/anglizismenindex/ag-anglizismenindex/) anbietet.

Unter social media wird als deutscher Begriff

> digitale Medien

vorgeschlagen. Allerdings halte ich diesen persönlich für irreführend im gewünschten Kontext.

Comment: Ja, "digitale Medien" trifft es nicht, denn das könnte ja auch ein klassischer Nachrichtenkanal sein, der statt über UKW etc. nur übers Internet (also "digital") sendet. Oder gar ein digital (im technischen Sinne, statt analog) ausgestrahlter Fernsehsender.

Comment: Es gibt hier (wie so oft) keinen Grund für Downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

Nach dem Lesen von rund einem Dutzend Kommentaren zu meiner Eingangsfrage sowie  der vier-fünf Antworten, die ebenfalls eingetroffen waren:

Vielen Dank für die vielen tiefsinnigen, teil auch gelungen amüsanten Beiträge! Nach dem Lesen (und vielleicht als Quintessenz) fiel mir ein Begriff ein, der für mich die Kriterien der Neutralität, Distanz und Präzision einigermaßen zu erfüllen scheint, vorerst und versuchsweise jedenfalls. Das wäre:

> Publikumsmedien

im Sinne von: Hier publiziert nicht eine (professionelle) Redaktion, sondern hier publiziert jedermann. Oder wenn schon denn schon:

> Jedermannmedien

und etwas präziser:

> elektronische Jedermannmedien

oder auch:

> audiovisuelle Jedermannmedien

---

Nachtrag

Ich bin andernorts jetzt auf den Begriff

> computersoziale Netzwerke

gestoßen, der mir ganz gut gefällt, weil er den Ausdruck "soziale Netzwerke" zwar verwendet (jeder weiß also gleich, um was es sich handelt, da der Ausdruck eben etabliert ist), ihn aber um eine die kritische Distanz signalisierende Präzisierung "computer" erweitert.

Comment: Bitte keine Danksagungen und Kommentare in Antworten. Du kannst Antworten, die Dir gefallen, aufwerten.

Comment: Wenn ich einen der Begriffe lesen würde hätte ich keinen Plan, was diese Aussagen sollen.

Comment: @userunknown  Der Dank ist hier nur die Einleitung zu meinen eigenen Lösungsvorschlägen.

Comment: @infinitezero  Das verstehe ich. Es wäre aber auch mit *soziale Medien* (oder *social media*) so, wüsstest du nicht aus anderer Quelle, was damit gemeint ist. Es ist eine Frage der Nutzungsfrequenz bzw. der Einführung des Begriffs. - Die Unerklärbarkeit des Gemeinten aus den semantischen Begriffselementen von *soziale Medien* war ja gerade Teil des Anlasses meiner Frage. Bei *Bohrmaschine* ist das besser: Das Wort erklärt sich von selbst. *Soziale Medien* erklärt sich nicht von selbst.

Comment: PS:  Ich möchte sogar behaupten, dass *audiovisuelle Jedermannmedien* sich besser von selbst erklärt als *soziale Medien*: "Aha, Audio; aha, Video; aha, Medien; das heißt, jemand publiziert hier. Und wer publiziert? Aha, jedermann!"

Comment: Soziale Medien ist aber schon der etablierte Begriff. Das krampfhafte Einführen von deutschen (TM) Begriffen kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Aber du kannst ja auch gerne zu Lichtspielhaus zurückkehren, wenn dir Kino nicht selbsterklärend genug ist.

Comment: @infinitezero  Wie gesagt, mich stört am Ausdruck *soziale Medien*, dass er irreleitend ist, jedenfalls solange man ein herkömmliches Verständnis des Worts "sozial" in der deutschen Sprache hat. Also suche ich Ersatz. Mit *Kino* habe ich dieses Problem nicht. Sagte man aber *Tonspielhaus* zum Kino (also unter offenkundiger Fehldarstellung der Tatsachen), dann würde ich vielleicht auch dieses Wort vermeiden.

Comment: @infinitezero Es ist doch völlig legitim, einen neuen deutschen Begriff für *social media* zu suchen. Ob das wirklich nötig ist, kann man natürlich bezweifeln. Wenn es eine schöne Wortschöpfung gäbe, wäre das auch nicht kramphaft. Leider sind aber alle Vorschläge lang und sperrig und - ja - klingen verkrampft.